# Alimentando lista codebehind e exibindo valor no asp

Tags: asp.net, webforms, vb.net, visual-basic-6

Estou pela primeira vez tendo contato mais profundo com uma aplicação em VB.NET. No caso, preciso alimentar uma lista que estou 'transformando em objeto' e posteriormente, exibir a mesma no meu asp. Geralmente estou acostumado com trabalhar com C# em MVC e por isso estou com séria dificuldade aqui.

Em meu codebehind tenho os métodos:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Pedidos = GetPedidos()
    DisplayList(Pedidos)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Sub DisplayList(ByVal Pedidos As IEnumerable(Of InformacoesPedido))
    For Each Pedido As InformacoesPedido In Pedidos
        Console.WriteLine("Nome do Agente: " & Pedido.Agente)
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next
End Sub

Function GetPedidos() As IEnumerable(Of InformacoesPedido)
    Dim MyConnectionCarrossel = New OleDbConnection(CONEXAO)
    MyConnectionCarrossel.Open()
    Dim ComandoCa As New OleDbCommand
    ComandoCa.Connection = MyConnectionCarrossel
    ComandoCa.CommandText = "SELECT * from tabela"
    Dim readerCa As OleDbDataReader = ComandoCa.ExecuteReader()

    Return New List(Of InformacoesPedido) From
        {
         New InformacoesPedido("Teste", "Teste 2", "Teste 3", "Teste 4", "Teste 5", "Teste 6")
        }

End Function

Public Class InformacoesPedido
    Public Property Agente As String
    Public Property Cliente As String
    Public Property Pedido As String
    Public Property Tipo As Integer
    Public Property Data As Integer
    Public Property ValorTotal As Integer

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal AgenteNome As String,
                   ByVal ClienteNome As String,
                   ByVal PedidoNome As String,
                   ByVal TipoNome As Integer,
                   ByVal DataPedido As Integer,
                   ByVal ValorTotalPedido As Integer)

        Agente = AgenteNome
        Cliente = ClienteNome
        Pedido = PedidoNome
        Tipo = TipoNome
        Data = DataPedido
        ValorTotal = ValorTotalPedido
    End Sub
End Class
```

A minha ideia era alimentar minha lista da seguinte forma:

```
Return New List(Of InformacoesPedido) From
        {
    While readerCa.Read
         New InformacoesPedido(readerCa.Item("X"), readerCa.Item("Y"), readerCa.Item("Z"), readerCa.Item("A"), readerCa.Item("B"), readerCa.Item("C"))
    End While
        }
```

Mas já vi que não é possível. Portanto, como poderia estar alimentando a minha lista a base da minha query?

Como posso chamar minha function `GetPedidos()` no asp para exibir os resultados obtidos?

---

@EDIT

Consegui acessar meu método da seguinte forma:

```
    <%For Each X In GetPedidos()%>
     <h2><%=X.Agente%></h2>
    <%Next%>
```

Meu maior problema agora é em como alimentar minha lista com os resultados da query

Removi o seguinte método:

```
Sub DisplayList(ByVal Pedidos As IEnumerable(Of InformacoesPedido))
For Each Pedido As InformacoesPedido In Pedidos
    Console.WriteLine("Nome do Agente: " & Pedido.Agente)
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Eu estou com um pouco de dificuldade em entender o seu codigo (VB para mim é grego), mas como acredito que o seu problema seja com o entimento do ciclo de vida de uma aplicação WebForms. você tem uma lista declarada dentro da sua Page, ela é carregada inicialmente no PageLoad, algum evento na sua pagina manipula esta lista, porem no CallBack a Lista não está disponivel. seria este o problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido

```
Dim Valores = New List(Of ProdutosPedido)
While readerCa.Read
Valores.Add(New ProdutosPedido(readerCa.Item("X"), readerCa.Item("Y"), readerCa.Item("Z"), readerCa.Item("A"), readerCa.Item("B"), readerCa.Item("C")))
End While
```